# Opening & forwarding MailDir files

Tags: email, gmail, maildir, email-forwarding

the domain I am working on recently moved from Squirrelmail to gmail. There are some old emails found in /home/user1/MailDir/ and I have to forward everything to gmail. All the mail files in this directory do not have a specific file extention. The only solution I have found is to open them with KMail and send each one manually. The problem is that the mails are more than 500 so forwarding them one by one is not the best idea. If you have any tips / suggestions, I would appreciate it.
Thanks